# Where do i get good quality (possibly free) templates in TEX for software development.

Tags: documentation

My documents include:

1. Functionality Specification
2. Software Requirement Specification
3. Software manual
4. High Level Design Document
5. Configuration Management.... and so on

Any TEX template for the above will be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The title of your posting states "software development", but the body of the posting seems to suggest you're looking for ideas on how to structure a document using (presumably) LaTeX. I wouldn't call this software development, though. Please consider editing your posting and clarifying what it is you're looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I think the examples shown on http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/miscellaneous are relatively close. I am not sure whether there are lots of templates for your special cases as they differ quite a bit between companies, environments, languages, etc.

Comment: If you are lucky you may find one for all 5, but see https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/ and https://www.writelatex.com/templates/ incase you can build on them.

Comment: How is a *High Level Design Document* supposed to look like? I myself don't have psychic powers and vote to close as unclear.